# Компонент не реагирует на изменения

Tags: javascript, vue.js

не могу разобраться с тем, почему не компонент не реагирует на изменение свойств объекта внутри массива. Суть:

```
computed: {
    device() {
      return this.$store.getters.getDevices;
    },
  },
```

возвращает массив с объектами. Когда их несколько - я использую:

```
<DeviceCardItem
        class="mb-3 col colCard"
        v-for="item of device"
        :key="item"
        v-bind:device="item"
        v-bind:isAdmin="isAdmin"
        v-bind:filtered="filterByDeviceId"
      />
```

и при изменении свойства (`device.is_active`) происходит то, что мне нужно.
Когда в массиве только один объект, я меняю код на:

```
computed: {
    device() {
      return this.$store.getters.getDevices[0];
    },
  },
```

и

```
<DeviceCardItem
        class="mb-3 col colCard"
        v-bind:device="device"
        v-bind:isAdmin="isAdmin"
        v-bind:filtered="filterByDeviceId"
      />
```

и пробую изменить тоже свойство (`device.is_active`) - я вижу, что в стейте оно изменяется, но компонент не изменяет то что мне нужно (а именно цвет блока).

Почему так?

Comment: А зачем менять алгоритм, если в массиве только один объект? Только лишняя путаница возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Если device - обычный массив, используйте for in

```
v-for="item in device"
```

и именуйте, согласно содержимому

```
get devices()
```

Не используйте объекты в качестве ключей.

```
v-for="(item, index) in device"
        :key="index"
```

```
v-for="item in device"
        :key="item._id" // если есть айди
```

При инициализирующем значении для $store.devices = undefined, реактивность не работает. Это должен быть пустой массив.

Почитайте про реактивность
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Когда я делаю :key="device.id" - перерисовка не происходит, при :key="device" - все рабоатет нормально.
В чем разница между v-for="item in device" v-for="item of device"? Гугление говорит что и тот и тот вариант верный

Comment: Точно не знаю в чем разница во Vue, но по крайней мере тем самым Вы не будите вводить в заблуждение, т.к. нативные for in и for of работают по-разному. Я ни разу не видел использование for of в шаблонах Vue. Уточните, какие данные Вы пытаетесь отрисовать?